# How to split an integer separate by tab/space into an array in map using java

Tags: split, integer

This is a map function. I have some random integers in Integer Value(input).

```
value= 1
       3
       2
       7
       9
    Integer line=value.toInteger();
    Integer[] a= line.split(" ");
```

but this is not correct I want to get the output like a[]={1 3 2 7 9 }.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I get your question right, But I think that this might work:

```
Integer[] a= line.split(" ");
for (i = 0; i< a.length; i++)
    Integer[i] = Integer.parseInt(Integer[i])
```

Best

Comment: May be this is python command. But I need java command. In Integer line I have many lines of integer ( suppose 1000 integer ) . I want to separate each integer into an array a but I think split is used for string not integer then what is the command for integer ?

Comment: You have to first split the string and find the string typed of each int and then convert it to int. I just change the code to Java version. Just a quick question, Do you want every int to be separate list or do you want all ints in a list?

Comment: Thank u so much I want the output like this a[4]={1,3, 2, 7, 9 } where a[0]=1 , a[1]=3,  , a[2]=2, a[3]=7, a[4]=9 .